# Powershell: How to scan a local area network without the knowledge of a subnet size

Tags: powershell, networking

I am trying to use PowerShell as a network scanning tool to ping every address on a local subnet. Any ping that is a success will be displayed together with an IP address of the destination device.

I have created two commands which will extract the IP and prefix length from `Get-NetIPAddress`:

```
$myIPAddress = $(Get-NetIPAddress | ? { ($_.AddressFamily -ilike "*IPv4*") -and ($_.IPAddress -notlike "127.0.0.1") -and ($_.IPAddress -notlike "169*") } | Select -ExpandProperty IPAddress)

$myPrefixLength = $(Get-NetIPAddress | ? { ($_.AddressFamily -ilike "*IPv4*") -and ($_.IPAddress -notlike "127.0.0.1") -and ($_.IPAddress -notlike "169*") } | Select -ExpandProperty PrefixLength)
```

I have also started it by making a tool that will essentially ping every address in a /24 space:

```
$ping = new-object system.net.networkinformation.ping; 1..254 | %  {$ping.send("192.168.43.$_", 1) | select address,status}
```

This is also taking in to account that the subnet space is known to be `/24` and the IP address begins with `192.168.43`.

What I am trying to achieve is variables, such as `1..254` and `"192.168.43.$_"` could be changed according to the IP address of the machine.

Could this be way beyond what I should be doing as a beginner? If so, what other networking tools I could try making which could be more simple to build for my level of knowledge?

Comment: What if you have a local network with an 8-bit network mask? That is 16,777,216 addresses to scan. That will take you a very long time. You can have a local network of an arbitrary size. Don't even think about IPv6, where most networks will have 18,446,744,073,709,551,616 possible addresses, and scanning 1,000,000/second will take over 584,542 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ron Maupin mentioned ,this might cause issues but I am assuming you are planning to use it on small test subnet.

you can utilize this module for getting ipaddresses in a subnet range

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Indented.Net.IP/5.0.12/Content/Indented.Net.IP.psm1
if you are using powershel V5 then you can use this command for the same `Install-Module Indented.Net.IP -Scope CurrentUser`

the below code snippet does what you were intending to do with the help of above module:

```
    Import-Module Indented.Net.IP
    $IPAddresses = $(Get-NetIPAddress | ? { ($_.AddressFamily -ilike "*IPv4*") -and ($_.IPAddress -notlike "127.0.0.1") -and ($_.IPAddress -notlike "169*") } )

    $ips = $ipaddresses | %{Get-NetworkRange "$($_.ipaddress)/$($_.prefixlength)"}

    $ping = new-object system.net.networkinformation.ping; $ips.ipaddresstostring | %  {$ping.send($_, 1) | select address,status}
```

Comment: ` PS C:\Users\User> Import-Module Indented.Net.IP
Import-Module : The specified module 'Indented.Net.IP' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any
module directory.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module Indented.Net.IP
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (Indented.Net.IP:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand `  
This is what i was issued when i entered ` Import-Module Indented.Net.IP `  My powershell version is 5.1

Comment: @MartinMartynasMarkevičius you have to run this command `Install-Module Indented.Net.IP -Scope CurrentUser` before you can import it(which I initially posted but someone edited my answer ,I have reverted the answer to the original